# collectionViewHeader not properly changing

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a search controller that when clicked presents a collectionViewController which has a different appearance depending on if you're the logged in user or a user I have searched up. This is the code that handles presenting the user

```
 weak var searchProfileViewController: SearchProfileeViewController?

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //        searchBar.isHidden = true
    //        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    switch scopeIndex {
    case 0:
        let event = filteredEvents[indexPath.item]
        currentEventDetailController.eventKey = event.key!
        currentEventDetailController.eventPromo = event.currentEventPromo!
        currentEventDetailController.currentEvent = event
        self.filteredEvents.removeAll()
        self.eventsArray.removeAll()
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        present(currentEventDetailController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        //  navigationController?.pushViewController(currentEventDetailController, animated: true)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
        break
    case 1:
        //change needs to be made here
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
        let user = filteredUsers[indexPath.item]
       // print(user.username ?? "")
        userProfileController.user = user
        userProfileController.navigationItem.title = user.username
        userProfileController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
        let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "icons8-Back-64"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(GoBack))
        userProfileController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
        var navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: userProfileController)
        present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        break
    default:
        break
    }

}
```

Now when a user controller is entered the header is configured using this code below which has two cases 
1. if you're the current logged in user
2. if you're a user I have searched for

```
 fileprivate func setupUserInteraction (){
        guard let currentLoggedInUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else{
            return
        }
        guard let uid = user?.uid else{
            return
        }

        if currentLoggedInUser == uid {
            let userStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [profileeSettings, settings])
            userStackView.distribution = .fillEqually
            userStackView.axis = .vertical
            userStackView.spacing = 10.0
            addSubview(userStackView)
            userStackView.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 15, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 90)
            let bottomDividerView = UIView()
            bottomDividerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            addSubview(bottomDividerView)
             bottomDividerView.anchor(top: profileStackView.bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 15, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0.5)

        } else{
            addSubview(followButton)
            followButton.anchor(top: profileStackView.bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 10, paddingLeft: 50, paddingBottom:0 , paddingRight: 50, width: 0, height: 0)
            let bottomDividerView = UIView()
            bottomDividerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
              addSubview(bottomDividerView)
             bottomDividerView.anchor(top: followButton.bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 15, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0.5)
            // check if following
            Database.database().reference().child("following").child(currentLoggedInUser).child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

                if let isFollowing = snapshot.value as? Int, isFollowing == 1 {

                    self.followButton.setTitle("Unfollow", for: .normal)

                } else {
                    self.setupFollowStyle()
                }

            }, withCancel: { (err) in
                print("Failed to check if following:", err)
            })

        }
    }
```

So here is where the problem comes in. When I go to the presented controller the first time it renders the proper cell based off of one of those two scenarios. However the second time that I go there it has pieces from the old header there so that my view ends up looking like this. Where it is rendering the header for a current logged in user as well as if I werent the current logged in user. Which can be seen by the appearance of both the follow button and the edit profile buttons

[image]

Which as you can see is clearly wrong because as a the current logged in user I shouldn't be able to follow myself. Also in the event that you go to another users profile you can edit information regarding them so things are just all messed up

The last thing I have added is the user variable and the corresponding didSet method

```
var user: User?{
    didSet {
        setupProfileImage()
        //  userNameLabel.text = user?.username
        setupUserInteraction()
    }
}
```

I appreciate any help

```
var header: UserProfileHeader?
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    header = (collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: headerID, for: indexPath) as! UserProfileHeader)
    header?.profileeSettings.addTarget(self, action: #selector(profileSettingsTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    header?.searchProfileViewController = self
    header?.settings.addTarget(self, action: #selector(settingsButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

    header?.user = self.user
    header?.backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(GoBack), for: .touchUpInside)
    return header!
}
```

Pic for logged in user profile
[image]

Comment: figured it out thanks though

Answer (score 0):

In first code I don't see where you hold userProfileController's variable. So I'm guessing userProfileController is class or global var. This means every time you present the same controller.

Every time you addSubview in

> setupUserInteraction ()

method. But there is no removeFromSuperview method.